# Interpreting yes/no responses in python

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to play around with some voice to text in python. Writing a bot to answer questions based on interpreting user voice input. One thing I'd like to do is interpret a wide range of responses for simple yes/no questions. I'm pretty new to language processing so this is more of an exploratory question. Could anyone point me to some resources that tackle this problem? My google fu seems to be failing me.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for resources.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: try googling :> "speech to text" and python<. Go through some sample code and tutorials. Try out something and then come back and ask for specific help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this library https://github.com/BlackriverBlockchain/anysolve under "Answer Yes/No Question about Text"

Disclaimer: I am the author of the library.